# C# Computer name or ip of computer on the network off drive letter

Tags: c#, networking

We are running our application over the network from a shared drive.

Is there a way in .Net to get the computer name of the mapped drive?

That's all I need! Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically discover mapped network drives on system and their server names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088752/how-to-programmatically-discover-mapped-network-drives-on-system-and-their-server)

Comment: Unless that gives me the UNC I don't see how it is a duplicate? Correct me if I am wrong, but I couldn't get a UNC out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WMI will give you this information.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088752/how-to-programmatically-discover-mapped-network-drives-on-system-and-their-server) is a great example, and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394592.aspx) are a few more examples.

Comment: I've got it to work on my local drive using the code. I'm new at this so bear with me but how do I use it to get a remote drive unc?

Comment: You could pull the `ProviderName` for the drive and parse out the remote system name.  Check the reference for the [Win32_LogicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173.aspx) class for information on what data you can retrieve about a drive.