# how to list logical drives without mapped drives

Tags: c#

I would like to populate a combo box with a list of logical drives but I would like to exclude any mapped drives. The code below gives me a list of all logical drives without any filtering.

```
comboBox.Items.AddRange(Environment.GetLogicalDrives());
```

Is there a method available that can help you determine between physical drives and mapped drives?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abt1306t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class

```
    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("  File type: {0}", d.DriveType);
        if(d.DriveType != DriveType.Network)
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add(d.Name);
        }
    }
```

exclude the drive when the property `DriveType` is `Network`

Answer (score 2):

Use [DriveInfo.GetDrives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx) to get the list of drives. You can then filter the list by its [DriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.drivetype.aspx) property.

Answer (score 2):

you can use  `DriveType` property in  the `DriveInfo` class

```
 DriveInfo[] dis = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
 foreach ( DriveInfo di in dis )
 {
     if ( di.DriveType == DriveType.Network )
     {
        //network drive
     }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you need `System.Management.dll`?

Answer (score 0):

One first thing that comes to mind is that the mapped drives will have the string beginning with `\\`

Another approach which is more extensive but more reliable is detailed here: [How to programmatically discover mapped network drives on system and their server names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088752/how-to-programmatically-discover-mapped-network-drives-on-system-and-their-serve)

---

Or try calling `DriveInfo.GetDrives()` which will give you objects with more metadata that will help you filter afterwards. Here's an example:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/159290/getting-mapped-drives-list

Comment: You can check for the "\\" by using `new Uri(drivePath).IsUnc`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx):

```
comboBox.Items.AddRange(
       System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                          .Where(di=>di.DriveType != DriveType.Network)
                          .Select(di=>di.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

The most complete information I found on this subject (after a long search on the internet) is available on Code Project: [Get a list of physical disks and the partitions on them in VB.NET the easy way](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/399828/Get-a-list-of-physical-disks-and-the-partitions-on)

(It's a VB project.)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
{
    if (d.IsReady && (d.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed || d.DriveType == DriveType.Removable))
    {
        cboSrcDrive.Items.Add(d.Name);
        cboTgtDrive.Items.Add(d.Name);
    }

}
```