# Finding drives connected in a network of systems

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I **find removable drives connected to a network of systems programmatically** using c#?
I mean I have been assigned with a project that to find and notify any removable drives connected to systems in my college lab.

Comment: For your reference - [How to programmatically discover mapped network drives on system and their server names?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1088752/455490)

Comment: Just to restate for clarity, you have a group of computers and from one computer you'd like to "know" if any other computers in this group  have removable drives connected? And this master computer will use ASP.Net for this task? Is this what your question is?

Comment: yeah that's what I need Mr. Haas

Comment: I was trying to find drives that are connected just in my system,  so am asking how to find others who have removable disk on them. I only get my removable drives...