# Get drive letter from USB mass storage device WIM

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

I have to write a function that returns all drive letters where the drive is a USB stick. The problem is that the USB sticks might be partitioned in way that Windows assigns 2 or more Drives to a single USB stick of which only one is a USB mass storage device(that is the letter that I want). So stuff like
`DriveInfo.GetDrives()` and then filtering with `device.DriveType == DriveType.Removable` does not work because that returns all the drives that are removable.

I have been trying to do it in WMI but so far I have not found the right answer. The most common answer to similiar questions is to go throug a few classes like this [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938686/how-to-get-the-drive-letter-of-usb-device-using-wmi/60548941):
`Win32_DiskDrive-> Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition -> Win32_DiskPartition -> Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition -> Win32_LogicalDisk` But that also returns all drives of the USB sticks. My thinking would be to remove all the drives that are not mass storage devices with `Win32_USBHub`. But I don't know where to add it in the chain or if that is even possible? Any help?

Comment: You only want the drives that "IsReady == true".  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645456/driveinfo-getdrives-show-not-connected-network-drives?force_isolation=true

Comment: No that does not change anything, both drives are ready

Comment: What happens if you use a file explorer to view the directories? If the file explorer is seeing both drives then the are mounted to the machine and are valid.

Comment: Yes I can see both with the explorer, but I only want the drive that has the USB logo in the explorer

Comment: You could get list of USB devices and check which ones are mounted as drivers (not serial) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.usb.usbdevice?force_isolation=true&view=winrt-19041

Comment: I am having trouble adding the Windows.Devices.Usb.dll to my project. I am getting this error message: "...Usb.dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component". Tried to register it with "regsvr32", but that also doesn't work

Comment: You need to use ImportDll.   You are using a unmanaged library which cannot be called from c# unless you use ImportDll.