# Get USB drive physical location and volumes using c#

Tags: c#, usb, volume

I´m trying to obtain the physical location of each USB drive or USB HDD connected to my personal computer and corresponding volume letters (drive letters). From google I just obtained the location information using the next code from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4c2849d3-15cd-4a9f-8971-166d5c0dc00d/c-find-specific-slot-no-of-the-usb-hub10-slots-where-usb-is-connected-or-not-i-want-to-get-the?forum=csharpgeneral) using `device.LocationInfo` like `Port_#0001.Hub_#0003`. With `Hub` referencing the hub the USB Drive is connected to, and `Port` the port used in it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GetUsbHubPort
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var deviceTree = new DeviceTree();

            foreach (var deviceClass in Win32.DeviceClasses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n{0}:", deviceClass.Value);

                foreach (var device in deviceTree.DeviceNodes
                    .Where(d => d.ClassGuid == deviceClass.Key))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "\t{1}: {0}",
                        device.Description,
                        device.EnumeratorName);
                }
            }

            Console.Write("\n\nAny key...");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }

    public class DeviceTree : IDisposable
    {
        private IntPtr _machineHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        private IntPtr _rootDeviceHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        private DeviceNode _rootNode;

        // flat collection of all devices found
        private List<DeviceNode> _deviceNodes;

        public DeviceNode RootNode
        {
            get
            {
                return this._rootNode;
            }
        }

        public List<DeviceNode> DeviceNodes
        {
            get
            {
                return this._deviceNodes;
            }
        }

        public DeviceTree()
        {
            EnumerateDevices();
        }

        ~DeviceTree()
        {
            this.Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                this._deviceNodes.Clear();
            }

            this.DisconnectFromMachine();
        }

        private void EnumerateDevices()
        {
            this.DisconnectFromMachine();

            // local machine assumed
            if (Win32.CM_Connect_Machine(
                null, ref this._machineHandle) != 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                Win32.CM_Locate_DevNode_Ex(
                    ref this._rootDeviceHandle,
                    0,
                    0,
                    this._machineHandle);

                // recursive enumeration
                this._rootNode = new DeviceNode(
                    this._rootDeviceHandle,
                    null,
                    this._machineHandle);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.DisconnectFromMachine();

                if (this._rootNode != null)
                {
                    this._deviceNodes = this._rootNode
                        .Flatten(node => node.Children).ToList();
                }
            }
        }

        private void DisconnectFromMachine()
        {
            if (this._machineHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Win32.CM_Disconnect_Machine(this._machineHandle);
                this._machineHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
    }

    public class DeviceNode : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly DeviceNode _parentDevice;
        private readonly List<DeviceNode> _children;
        private readonly IntPtr _deviceHandle;
        private readonly IntPtr _machineHandle;

        private readonly Dictionary<int, string>
            _deviceProperties;

        public DeviceNode ParentDevice
        {
            get
            {
                return _parentDevice;
            }
        }

        public Dictionary<int, string> DeviceProperties
        {
            get
            {
                return _deviceProperties;
            }
        }

        public List<DeviceNode> Children
        {
            get
            {
                return this._children;
            }
        }

        public Guid ClassGuid
        {
            get
            {
                string buffer =
                    this.GetProperty(Win32.DevRegProperty.ClassGuid);

                var guid = new Guid();

                if (buffer.Length >= 32)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        guid = new Guid(buffer);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        guid = new Guid();
                    }
                }

                return guid;
            }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return
                    GetProperty(Win32.DevRegProperty.DeviceDescription);
            }
        }

        public string FriendlyName
        {
            get
            {
                return
                    GetProperty(Win32.DevRegProperty.FriendlyName);
            }
        }

        public string EnumeratorName
        {
            get
            {
                return
                    GetProperty(Win32.DevRegProperty.EnumeratorName);
            }
        }

        public string LocationInfo
        {
            get
            {
                return
                    GetProperty(Win32.DevRegProperty.LocationInfo);
            }
        }

        public DeviceNode(IntPtr deviceHandle, DeviceNode parentDevice)
            : this(
                    deviceHandle,
                    parentDevice,
                    parentDevice._machineHandle)
        {
        }

        public DeviceNode(
            IntPtr deviceHandle,
            DeviceNode parentDevice,
            IntPtr machineHandle)
        {
            _deviceProperties = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            _children = new List<DeviceNode>();

            _deviceHandle = deviceHandle;
            _machineHandle = machineHandle;
            _parentDevice = parentDevice;

            EnumerateDeviceProperties();
            EnumerateChildren();
        }

        private string GetProperty(
            Win32.DevRegProperty devRegProperty)
        {
            return GetProperty((int)devRegProperty);
        }

        private string GetProperty(int index)
        {
            string buffer;
            var result = this._deviceProperties
                .TryGetValue(index, out buffer);
            return result ? buffer : string.Empty;
        }

        private void EnumerateDeviceProperties()
        {
            for (var index = 0; index < 64; index++)
            {
                uint bufsize = 2048;

                IntPtr buffer =
                    Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)bufsize);

                var result =
                    Win32.CM_Get_DevNode_Registry_Property_Ex(
                        _deviceHandle,
                        index,
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        buffer,
                        ref bufsize,
                        0,
                        _machineHandle);

                var propertyString = result == 0
                    ? Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer)
                    : string.Empty;

                _deviceProperties.Add(index, propertyString);

                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
            }
        }

        private void EnumerateChildren()
        {
            IntPtr ptrFirstChild = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (Win32.CM_Get_Child_Ex(
                ref ptrFirstChild,
                _deviceHandle,
                0,
                _machineHandle) != 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            var ptrChild = ptrFirstChild;
            var ptrSibling = IntPtr.Zero;

            do
            {
                var childDevice = new DeviceNode(ptrChild, this);
                _children.Add(childDevice);

                if (Win32.CM_Get_Sibling_Ex(
                    ref ptrSibling,
                    ptrChild,
                    0,
                    _machineHandle) != 0) break;

                ptrChild = ptrSibling;
            }
            while (true);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _deviceProperties.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    internal static class LinqExtensionMethods
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Return<T>(T element)
        {
            yield return element;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> StartWith<T>(
            this IEnumerable<T> list, T element)
        {
            return Return(element).Concat(list);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TEntity> Flatten<TEntity>(
            this TEntity element,
            Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TEntity>> childSelector)
        {
            if (childSelector(element) != null)
                return childSelector(element)
                    .SelectMany(child => child.Flatten(childSelector))
                    .StartWith(element);

            var items = new List<TEntity> { element };
            return items;
        }
    }

    public static class Win32
    {
        // this is a partial list
        public static readonly
            Dictionary<Guid, string> DeviceClasses =
            new Dictionary<Guid, string>
            {
                { new Guid("{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"),
                    "Disk Drives" },
                { new Guid("{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"),
                    "Display Adapters" },
                { new Guid("{4d36e96b-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"),
                    "Keyboards" },
                { new Guid("{4d36e96f-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"),
                    "Mice" },
            };

        public enum DevRegProperty : uint
        {
            DeviceDescription = 1,
            HardwareId = 2,
            CompatibleIds = 3,
            Unused0 = 4,
            Service = 5,
            Unused1 = 6,
            Unused2 = 7,
            Class = 8,
            ClassGuid = 9,
            Driver = 0x0a,
            ConfigFlags = 0x0b,
            Mfg = 0x0c,
            FriendlyName = 0x0d,
            LocationInfo = 0x0e,
            PhysicalDeviceObjectName = 0x0f,
            Capabilities = 0x10,
            UiNumber = 0x11,
            UpperFilters = 0x12,
            LowerFilters = 0x13,
            BusTypeGuid = 0x014,
            LegacyBusType = 0x15,
            BusNumber = 0x16,
            EnumeratorName = 0x17,
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern uint GetLogicalDrives();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetDriveType(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string rootPathName);

        [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll")]
        public static extern int CM_Connect_Machine(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string uncServerName,
            ref IntPtr machineHandle);

        [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll")]
        public static extern int CM_Disconnect_Machine(
            IntPtr machineHandle);

        [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll")]
        public static extern int CM_Locate_DevNode_Ex(
            ref IntPtr deviceHandle,
            int deviceId,
            uint flags,
            IntPtr machineHandle);

        [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll")]
        public static extern int CM_Get_Child_Ex(
            ref IntPtr childDeviceHandle,
            IntPtr parentDeviceHandle,
            uint flags,
            IntPtr machineHandle);

        [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll")]
        public static extern int CM_Get_Sibling_Ex(
            ref IntPtr siblingDeviceHandle,
            IntPtr deviceHandle,
            uint flags,
            IntPtr machineHandle);

        [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll")]
        public static extern int
            CM_Get_DevNode_Registry_Property_Ex(
                IntPtr deviceHandle,
                int property,
                IntPtr regDataType,
                IntPtr outBuffer,
                ref uint size,
                int flags,
                IntPtr machineHandle);
    }
}
```

Now I just need to link this device with volume (drive letters) contained in it. Any idea will be appreciatted.

Comment: Your question reads like "I found this code on the Internet that I don't fully understand, and I need your help modifying it to meet my specific requirements."

Comment: In fact is my first time using PInvoke. I already understand the code but I don´t known with the info it provide how to get the drive letters if any. Any help will be welcome :)

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1088752/102937) what you're looking for?

Comment: In addition to looking for storage devices on the USB bus, you need to look for devices with the "Volume" class GUID.  They will be children of the storage devices.  Open your Device Manager and switch to the "By Connection" view to see the relationship.

Comment: Sorry @RobertHarvey this wasn´t what I was looking for but it really answer another of my problems so I will upvote you ;)

Comment: Ok @BenVoigt I think this is the way. I will check if using the Volume class GUID in the DeviceClasses dictionary I can found the info needed